# Has this plot ever been done?

Tags: analysis, genre

Is there a movie where the hero protagonist has an obvious advantage in terms of strength or technology, but against all the odds, ultimately succumbs to the under dog villain?

I can't think of a single plot that follows this model.

Comment: Some combination of [Pyrrhic Villainy](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PyrrhicVillainy) and [The Bad Guy Wins](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheBadGuyWins)?

Comment: Pretty sure it has.

Comment: Many will consider this a stretch, but - in a way - "The Dark Knight". If we're to consider the ending to be the Batman's victory, then it's a [Pyrrhic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory) one, and the Joker certainly starts as an apparent underdog: he is described as just some man that did an "armed robbery, double homicide, has a taste for the theatrical..." and early in the movie the Batman even says "One man or the whole mob? He can wait", clearly underestimating him.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your answer. Silent of the Lambs is a good example of an underdog villain wining, not the main villain, also not as accurate: The Dark Knight, Seven.

Comment: 3:10 to Yuma, remake

Answer (score 2):

One more recent (2010) movie that follows this plot is the animated comedy "Megamind". Slight technicality here as the "underdog villain" is the protagonist of the film, and later in the story changes roles to the "hero" protagonist.